# DDR3 DQS "preamble"

Tags: timing, sdram, ddr3

I'm building a small testbench for a DDR3 memory controller and would like to verify that my unterstanding of DQS and DQ sampling points is correct.

The line state before the transmission is undefined (so it can be high), and therefore a component that takes over control will have to send a `'1'` on DQS first, followed by a `'0'` (which is the first transition that is guaranteed to be received), and data is then sampled on consecutive edges, starting with the first rising edge.

If another transfer driven from the same chip follows, it can be appended directly, so the waveform for two consecutive 8 word bursts looks like

[image: DDR3 DQS vs DQ]

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's correct, as long as the same rank and bank are being accessed. Consecutive burst-8’s don't insert any dead cycles on DQ/DQS.

More here: https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse467/11wi/lectures/SDRAM.pdf

Comment: Wait, "same bank" is a restriction for back-to-back transfers? My expectation would be that if I generate addresses in row-bank-column order and issue the PRE and ACT commands to one bank while another is transferring, I can get an uninterrupted stream of data with one transfer on every clock edge.

Comment: You’ll need to check the specification on that. At some point you’ll need to run the pre-charge cycle to write the page back to the cells that have lost their charge during access.